# Java adds object to wrong vector (it is not even written in code that it should)

Tags: java, oop

Let's suppose we have 1 class called `GroupOfStudents`, which has one property named `vectorOfStudents`. So, that class looks like this:

```
public class GroupOfStudents{
    public Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>();   
    public GroupOfStudents(Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents) {
        this.vectorOfStudents = vectorOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Ok, simple, right ? Also, we have one class called `Student` and let's say it just has student's name as property.

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now, let's create 2 groups without any students.

```
Vector<Student> emptyVectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>();
GroupOfStudents group1 = new GroupOfStudents(emptyVectorOfStudents);    
GroupOfStudents group2 = new GroupOfStudents(emptyVectorOfStudents);
```

And, of course, let's give `group1` for example 1 student, called "Luke".

```
Student student1 = new Student("Luke");
group1.vectorOfStudents.add(student1);
```

Let second group remain empty. When I want to output names of students of both groups, for some reason, `group2` has also `student1` in its vector.

```
for(Student s: group1.vectorOfStudents) {
    System.out.print("Name: " + s.name + " ");
}
System.out.println("");
for(Student s: group2.vectorOfStudents) {
    System.out.print("Name: " + s.name + " ");
}
```

Output is:

```
Name: Luke
Name: Luke
```

And it should be:

```
Name: Luke (because second group has no students)
```

Any reason why this happens ?

Comment: You're passing the same `Vector` to both instances of `GroupOfStudents`.

Comment: I want to pass empty vector and then expand it later.. Any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is not even written in code that it should

Yes, it is, here:

```
Vector<Student> emptyVectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>();
GroupOfStudents group1 = new GroupOfStudents(emptyVectorOfStudents);    
GroupOfStudents group2 = new GroupOfStudents(emptyVectorOfStudents);
```

Both `group1` and `group2` use the **same** Vector. If you want them to have separate vectors, give them separate vectors:

```
GroupOfStudents group1 = new GroupOfStudents(new Vector<Student>());    
GroupOfStudents group2 = new GroupOfStudents(new Vector<Student>());
```

---

Note that your `GroupOfStudents` code is creating a Vector already on construction, but then throwing it away to use the one it receives as a constructor parameter:

```
public class GroupOfStudents{
    // Creates a new Vector when an instance is created
    public Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>(); 
    public GroupOfStudents(Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents) {
        // Throws away the Vector created above and uses the one from the parameter instead
        this.vectorOfStudents = vectorOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Probably best to just ditch the parameter and not pass in a Vector at all, either:

```
public class GroupOfStudents{
    public Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>(); 
    public GroupOfStudents() {
    }
}
```

or

```
public class GroupOfStudents{
    public Vector<Student> vectorOfStudents; 
    public GroupOfStudents() {
        this.vectorOfStudents = new Vector<Student>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you want to use a `Vector`? The [documentation of `Vector` itself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) states that:

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

Second, if you want to pass the `Collection` to your constructor class(es), you may want to copy the `Collection`s before storing them in a local field (e.g. through [`Collections.copy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,java.util.List))). The Java API is suboptimal designed here. Not all `Collection`s define a copy-constructor, and [`Cloneable` is not an option](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-copy-constructor-preferred-over-Cloneable-and-the-clone-method-in-Java). So we have to work with what we have got. But hey! If everything were easy, it would be boring, wouldn't it? :)